# Appium + Puppeteer : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started

Tags: automation, puppeteer, appium

I have an issue with running Appium and a script using puppeteer,
so what's the case im trying to do:
First im running a test that will make an order and keep going with the order's status until its delivered
After that im running a puppeteer script using the shell to add deduction on the order and compensation for driver
After the shell finished with running the script this error appears ( ill post it at the end )

if there is a way to run the shell and after that keep the other cases running on app

these info might be helpful :
Appium version : 1.22.3
IDE : IntelliJ
Java version : 19.0.1
Language : Java

`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: A session is either terminated or not started Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'Ezaldeens-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:88e:741f:94e8:1ae9%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.5', java.version: '11.0.12' Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver Capabilities {app: /Users/ezaldeenaleses/Docum..., automationName: XCUITest, browserName: , databaseEnabled: false, deviceName: iPhone 12 Pro Max, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: false, platform: MAC, platformName: iOS, takesScreenshot: true, udid: AC051667-40DE-4D83-8811-E2C..., wdaLocalPort: 10051, webStorageEnabled: false, webkitDebugProxyPort: 11052} Session ID: 85891848-b54b-4bd9-8850-f7c4ec2e0b64.`

```
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:45)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.InteractsWithApps.closeApp(InteractsWithApps.java:140)
at com.chef.invoice.base.BaseTest.closeApp(BaseTest.java:75)
at com.chef.invoice.tests.AddDeductAndComp.afterClass(AddDeductAndComp.java:25)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:217)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:130)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```